# How to exclude interaction terms in stargazer?

Tags: r, stargazer

I have a regression with several variables but only want to include one of them in the regression output. The regression also includes interaction terms and I do not want the interaction terms included in the output.

```
library(stargazer)

reg1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt, data = mtcars)
reg2 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp*wt, data = mtcars)

stargazer(reg1, reg2, keep = "hp", omit = ":", type = "text")
```

The output of the above code includes the independent variables "hp" and "hp:wt". I would like the stargazer output to only include "hp." Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If we use keep, it will present all the rows having that variable. If use omit, it will remove all the rows having that variable. It is better to use omit for all the variables except the one we need.

```
library(stargazer)

reg1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt, data = mtcars)
reg2 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp*wt, data = mtcars)

stargazer(reg1, reg2, omit = c("cyl", "Constant", "wt"), type = "text")
```

Output

```
> stargazer(reg1, reg2, omit = c("cyl", "Constant", "wt"), type = "text")

=================================================================
                                 Dependent variable:             
                    ---------------------------------------------
                                         mpg                     
                             (1)                    (2)          
-----------------------------------------------------------------
hp                          -0.018               -0.108***       
                           (0.012)                (0.030)        

-----------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                  32                     32          
R2                          0.843                  0.887         
Adjusted R2                 0.826                  0.870         
Residual Std. Error    2.512 (df = 28)        2.172 (df = 27)    
F Statistic         50.171*** (df = 3; 28) 52.944*** (df = 4; 27)
=================================================================
Note:                                 *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```