# Stargazer omits one row of coefficients when using keep or omit

Tags: stargazer

I've identified a bug in R's stargazer package that results in the last row of covariates being deleted when printing multiple models and using either the "keep" or "omit" function to suppress the printing of certain covariates (e.g. fixed effects for example, or the intercept).

```
data("mtcars")
names(mtcars)
mod<-lm(mpg~hp+wt+disp+carb+gear+vs+cyl+drat+am+hp*wt, data=mtcars)
mod1<-lm(mpg~hp+wt+disp+carb+gear+vs+cyl+drat+am+hp*wt, data=mtcars)
list1<-list(mod, mod1)
library(stargazer)
#Print multiple models, bug appears
stargazer(list1, type="html", omit=10)
#Print one model, bug does not appear
stargazer(mod, type="html", omit=10)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what row you are missing? Should it be html output? Are you especially interested in the interaction?

Answer (score 0):

When I ask stargazer to show 2 models with either the `keep` or `omit` option, it shows what I asked for:

```
library(stargazer)
data("mtcars")
mod1<-lm(mpg~cyl+wt, data=mtcars)
mod2<-lm(mpg~disp+wt, data=mtcars)

stargazer(mod1, mod2, type="text", keep = "wt", omit.stat=c("LL","ser","f", "n", "rsq", "adj.rsq"))


==================================
          Dependent variable:     
      ----------------------------
                  mpg             
           (1)            (2)     
----------------------------------
wt      -3.191***      -3.351***  
         (0.757)        (1.164)   
                                  
==================================

stargazer(mod1, mod2, type="text", omit = "wt", omit.stat=c("LL","ser","f", "n", "rsq", "adj.rsq"))

=====================================
             Dependent variable:     
         ----------------------------
                     mpg             
              (1)            (2)     
-------------------------------------
cyl        -1.508***                 
            (0.415)                  
                                     
disp                       -0.018*   
                           (0.009)   
                                     
Constant   39.686***      34.961***  
            (1.715)        (2.165)   
                                     
=====================================
```

If you like to see how to turn on/off the interaction term components, check out [How to exclude interaction terms in stargazer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61326886/how-to-exclude-interaction-terms-in-stargazer)